# Number of weekend days per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to determine the number of weekend days in each month based on a `CreateDate` field.

My current attempts seems to be off by 1 day when there are 31 days in the month.

**Can anyone explain why this is happening?**

```
;WITH cteNetProfit
AS (
---- NET PROFIT
SELECT    DT.CreateDate
       , SUM(DT.Revenue) AS Revenue
       , SUM(DT.Cost) AS Cost
       , SUM(DT.GROSSPROFIT) AS GROSSPROFIT
FROM
        (
        SELECT CAST([createDTG] AS DATE) AS CreateDate
            , SUM(Revenue) AS Revenue
            , SUM(Cost) AS Cost
            , SUM(REVENUE - COST) AS GROSSPROFIT
        FROM     [dbo].[CostRevenueSpecific]
        WHERE   CAST([createDTG] AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 91 AS DATE)
               AND CAST([createDTG] AS DATE) < = CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE)
        GROUP BY createDTG
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST([CallDate] AS DATE) AS CreateDate
            , SUM(Revenue) AS Revenue
            , SUM(Cost) AS Cost
            , SUM(REVENUE - COST) AS GROSSPROFIT
        FROM   [dbo].PublisherCallByDay
        WHERE  CAST([CallDate] AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 91 AS DATE)
              AND CAST([CallDate] AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE)
        GROUP BY CALLDATE) DT
GROUP BY DT.CreateDate),
A1
AS (SELECT DISTINCT
         MONTH(CREATEDATE) AS MONTHNO
        , DAY(EOMONTH(CreateDate)) AS DaysinMth
    FROM   cteNetProfit),
A2
AS (
SELECT A.MONTHNO
    , COUNT(A.WorkDay) AS DAYSPERMTH
    , A.WorkDay
FROM
        (SELECT MONTH(CREATEDATE) AS MONTHNO
             , CHOOSE
               (DATEPART(dw, CreateDate), 'WEEKEND', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'WEEKEND') AS WorkDay
         FROM   cteNetProfit) A
WHERE   A.WORKDAY = 'WEEKEND'
GROUP BY A.MONTHNO
      , A.WorkDay
UNION
SELECT A.MONTHNO
    , COUNT(A.WorkDay) AS DAYSPERMTH
    , A.WorkDay
FROM
      (SELECT MONTH(CREATEDATE) AS MONTHNO
           , CHOOSE
            (DATEPART(dw, CreateDate), 'WEEKEND', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'WEEKEND') AS WorkDay
       FROM   cteNetProfit) A
WHERE  A.WORKDAY = 'WEEKDAY'
GROUP BY A.MONTHNO
      , A.WorkDay),
A3
AS (SELECT A1.MONTHNO
        , A1.DaysinMth
        , A2.DAYSPERMTH
        , A2.WorkDay
        , CASE
            WHEN A2.WorkDay = 'WEEKEND' THEN SUM(A2.DAYSPERMTH) / 2
            ELSE A2.DAYSPERMTH
         END AS DP_REV
    FROM   a1
         INNER JOIN A2 ON A1.MONTHNO = A2.MONTHNO
    GROUP BY A1.MONTHNO
         , A1.DaysinMth
         , A2.DAYSPERMTH
         , A2.WorkDay),
A4
AS (SELECT A3.MONTHNO
        , A3.DAYSINMTH
        , SUM(A3.DP_REV) AS DPREV
    --  , A3.DP_REV
    FROM   A1
         INNER JOIN A3 ON A1.MONTHNO = A3.MONTHNO
    GROUP BY A3.MONTHNO
         , A3.DaysinMth)
SELECT A1.MONTHNO
    , A1.DAYSINMTH
    , A4.DPREV
    , A3.DP_REV
    , A3.DAYSPERMTH
FROM   A1
    , A3
    , A4
WHERE  A1.MONTHNO = A4.MONTHNO
      AND A1.MONTHNO = A3.MONTHNO;
```

[image: Sample]

As you can see the highlighted numbers do not equal total days in month.

Comment: Kind of hard to follow your query, but have you considered counting the days `WHERE DATEPART(weekday,[YourDate]) NOT IN (0,1)` and group on your month?

Comment: you should build a date_dim table which will have flags for weekends.  This one is my fave, but there are a bunch: [date_dim link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest solution would be to create a `Calendar` table to store list of months together with their number of days and number of weekend days:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar.Month (
    YearMonth INT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    Year SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Month TINYINT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (Year, Month),
    NumDays TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK(NumDays BETWEEN 28 AND 31),
    WeekendDays TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK(WeekendDays > 0),
    CHECK (WeekendDays < NumDays),
    NonWeekendDays AS (DaysNum - WeekendDays)
) 
-- Plus INSERT INTO Calendar.Month (...) VALUES (...) statements
```

and then we have to use a simple join to get required dataL

```
SELECT ..., m.WeekendDays
FROM dbo.SourceTable s
INNER JOIN Calendar.Month m ON m.Year = YEAR(s.CreateDate) AND m.Month = MONTH(s.CreateDate)
-- Above join predicate it's not so nice but performance should be good because of UNIQUE CLUSTERED index defined on Year and Month columns
```

Comment: If you are going to create a calendar table, why not have a record for each date?  That would be a lot more useful.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Because I want to avoid computation of number of weekdays. Such computation involves filtering rows on date column and IsWeekend and then COUNT. If Source table contain 1000 rows with the same CreateDate then ~ 1000 times SQL Server will have to compute and recompute the same value.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input and assistance, I ended up going with a Calendar table and reworking the rest of my code to incorporate this new table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment.  I will start with two assumptions.  The first is that you don't have a calendar table, ie a database table with a row for every date.  The second is that your application does not necessarily create records every day.   Based on those assumptions, I suggest the following approach.

1. Create a variable named @startDate from the year and month of your date in question.  Make it the first of the month.
2. Create a variable named @endDate by adding one month (using datediff of course) to @startDate and then subtracting one day.
3. Create and populate a table variable with all the dates between those two variables.  There are lots of examples on the web on how to do this.
4. Use date functions on this temporary table to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "tally table" to create a calendar of dates, starting from a given date.  I used a variable, in this example, as a starting date.  I have two CTE's.  The first one takes a tally table and produces 10,000 dates, starting with the variable date, using the DATEADD function.  Using the DATEPART function, I can determine the MONTH, YEAR and WEEKDAY of each date.

For the WeekendDays query (first CTE), I just get a count of WEEKDAY values that are either 1 or 7 (Sunday or Saturday).  For the WeekDays CTE, at the bottom, I do the same thing, but I exclude WEEKDAY values that are 1 or 7.

```
DECLARE @StartingDate DATE

SET @StartingDate = '2015-01-01'

;WITH TallyTable AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.id) AS N
    FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns a, Master.dbo.SysColumns b

)
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate)) AS [Year], DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate)) AS [MONTH]
,COUNT(DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate))) AS [WeekendDays]
FROM TallyTable
WHERE DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate))  IN(7,1)
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate)), DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate))
ORDER BY [Year], [MONTH]


;WITH TallyTable AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.id) AS N
    FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns a, Master.dbo.SysColumns b

)
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate)) AS [Year], DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate)) AS [MONTH]
,COUNT(DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate))) AS [WeekendDays]
FROM TallyTable
WHERE DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate))  NOT IN(7,1)
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate)), DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartingDate))
ORDER BY [Year], [MONTH]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query. It also consider leap year.

```
with cte as (
select top (IIF(DATEPART(dd,(EOMONTH(CONCAT(2016,'0201')))) = 29, 366, 365)) 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by column_id) X
from sys.columns
)
, ds as (
select dateadd(day, X - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(2016, 1, 1)) dt
from cte
)
, W as (
select dt, DATEPART(w, dt) WD, DATEPART(month, dt) Mon
from ds
where DATEPART(w, dt) in (1, 7)
)
select Mon TheMonth, ceiling(1.0*COUNT(*)/2) AS NumberOfWeekEnds
from W
group by Mon
```

**Result**

```
TheMonth    NumberOfWeekEnds
1           5
2           4
3           4
4           5
5           5
6           4
7           5
8           4
9           4
10          5
11          4
12          5
```